# Why does CompletableFuture.runAsync() not always submit to ForkJoinPool.commonPool()?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future, forkjoinpool

[`CompletableFuture.runAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable)) documentation states:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()) after it runs the given action.

However, as far as I can tell, `runAsync` only submits a task to `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` when `ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() > 1`. If not, it manually creates a new `Thread` for each submitted task.

Why exactly is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if ForkJoinPool parallelism level is less than 2, then new thread is created for every task [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable))

> All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() **(unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task).**

Comment: I can see that, but I would like some elaboration on why it would be better (assuming it is, since it was implemented this way) to spawn new threads in case the parallelism level is not greater than 1 (so, by default, when you have one or two logical cores).